# cross store support spring - lazy fetch

Tags: spring, mongodb, jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to use the cross store feature but before implementing it i would like to know what happens in the following case:

lets say i have an entity :

```
@entity
public myEntity {

@relatedDocument
private RawData doc;
}
```

since this RawData class is huge, 
i would like to know if i can use the lazy fetching on this field when i query for myEntity class...

couldn't find it on the spring source documentation.

p.s anyone worked with it and can rate this feature (cross store )?
thanks

Comment: I found [this article](http://www.littlelostmanuals.com/2011/10/example-cross-store-with-mongodb-and.html) when playing with spring data mongodb. Maybe it could be of some use.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and looked at the MongoDB Cross-Store module documentation and source code around Apr-2013.  I did not find anything that would suggest that lazy loading is supported with any of the Spring Data Cross-Store modules.  Looking at the source code (at that time), I saw that cross-store entities are loaded by hooking into the JPA PostLoad lifecycle event and persisted by hooking into the JPA PostPersist event.

I could not come up with a simple way to implement lazy loading because cross-store persistence is really a Spring Data functionality whereas lazy loading is implemented by the JPA provider, which is completely ignorant of any other persistence managers in use.

Unless the cross-store modules have been changed since Apr-2013, I doubt that lazy loading is supported for cross-store entities yet.